Book read in the 80s or 90s where the hero's life is ruined by a tax assessment before he could discredit a man running for world president
The hero got a tax assessment which ruined his life. He was about to discredit a politician / prophet who is running for I think world president. If he gains power everyone will have to take a pill with 50% of them being poison so solving the overpopulation problem.  It was set in America.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The antagonist has the power to kill half the world, and they have to use a tax burden against the protagonist?  How does that prevent him from defeating the antagonist?

Why the [tag:genetics] tag? Are there genetics-related details that you remember and forgot to write in the question? If so, remember that you can always [edit] your question to add details.

It was Natures End by Whitley Strieber and  James Kunetka

It is 2025 and the planet is rapidly approaching environmental death. Dr. Gupta Singh, a Hindu guru with a Jim Jones-like following, has proposed the suicide, by lottery, of one-third of the world's population. His followers have elected a Depopulationist majority in Congress. Led by journalist John Sinclair, a small group hopes to prove that Singh is a fraud. Singh is a formidable enemy: he cancels the medical-cosmetological treatment that the 72-year-old Sinclair (who looks 46 due to the treatment) receives, causing Sinclair to age rapidly. Singh sets the feared tax police after Sinclair, alters his records, and wipes out his wealth. Tension mounts as Sinclair stalks Singh and gains access to his "conviction", an electronic document into Singh's true identity and character.


You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].
